# OpenGl Blending

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, color-blending

i want to blend two rects, but i want to draw only blended area (area where rects are intersecting), How to do it

Comment: Make yourself registered user. You will have more answers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to compute the intersection you can probably use the stencil buffer to achieve that. read about it here:
http://bluevoid.com/opengl/sig00/advanced00/notes/node118.html

You can draw the two rects and with increment on the stencil buffer and then mask only the pixels that have value > 2, i.e. the pixels where 2 or more rects were drawn.

Comment: I dont think thats possible, or maybe i dont fully understand how stencil buffer works, i have one big vertex array with all rects inside, i cannot draw them one by one because there are lot of them and its very slow. I need to go deeper with scencil :)

Answer (score 0):

The intersection of two convex rects is always a rect. so why not just compute the intersection and draw only the that?

Comment: Only if they are axis aligned ;)

Comment: Well, they are axix aligned but calculating those intersections may be slow, i have about 400 rects and 1ghz hummingbird.

Answer (score 0):

```
GLES20.glEnable( GLES20.GL_BLEND );
GLES20.glBlendFunc( GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
```

But you should set behavior of your blend function yourown.
And in the shader I set alpha channel. You can see the result:

[blending post](http://www.vikulov.net/2011/04/opengl-es-20-android_10.html).
the [source](http://code.google.com/p/android-opengles-samples-for-vikulov-blogspot-com/source/browse/trunk/OpenglTemplate/src/com/vikulov/opengl/MyGLRenderer.java) of android project